# Effect of Previous UK Removal of non-EU spouse on EU-national

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-spouses

I am a Pakistani national married to an EU national. I have been deported from UK. My wife has left the UK with me and now we wish to move together to another EU state.

Would my deportation from UK have an impact on my travel to another EU state?

Comment: I edited the grammar of your question to improve its clarity, and tried to not change the meaning. If you disagree with the changes, you may revert the text to what you originally posted.

Comment: It might, depending on the reason for your deportation.

Comment: This is a question for [Expatriates.SE].

Answer (score 7):

Since the EU free movement system still applies in the UK, you should only have been expelled from the UK for one of a limited set of reasons:

- you were found to pose a threat to public health, public policy, or public safety
- your marriage was found not to be genuine
- your wife was found not to be a "qualified" EU citizen (that is, she was neither working nor studying, nor did she have sufficient resources to support the two of you in the UK).

Since you say that *you* were deported, not she, I assume that the last reason does not apply.

Your removal from the UK cannot be by itself grounds for denying your admission to another EU country.  But the reason for that removal is likely to be sufficient for another country to refuse entry.  For example, if the UK found you to be a threat to public safety, or found that your marriage is not genuine, another country may well make the same finding.

Without having more specific information about your circumstances, it is not possible to offer a more specific answer to your question.

Comment: Well citizen directive states that , previous criminal convictions doesn't constitute a threat by it self.... Now my previous convictions happen some 6 years ago ....

Comment: @AliAhmed Assume the deportation will be known. This is a case that should be dealt with by a immigration lawyer.

Comment: @AliAhmed "previous criminal convictions doesn't constitute a threat by itself": for that reason, your 6-year-old conviction should not have been grounds to remove you from the UK.  But you were removed.  That implies that there is some additional factor that caused the UK to find that you are a threat to public safety (or that you were subject to removal for one of the other reasons).

Comment: @MarkJohnson on the contrary, a reasonable approach in this case would be to apply for a visa (if needed) and residence card in another EU country.  It would only be necessary to hire a lawyer if these are refused.

Comment: @phoog I think it would wiser to have an experienced lawyer prepare the visa application that contains all information about the deportation and previous convections. An upfront approach, dealing with these matters, is more likely to succeed.

Comment: @MarkJohnson perhaps so.

Comment: @phoog ‘previous criminal conviction doesn’t constitute a threat by itself’ - out of interest, might that depend on the nature of the criminal conviction? Eg driving convictions vs assault/bodily harm or drug-related convictions?

Comment: @Traveller In Germany this may be the case since the 'Basic Criminal Record' does not contain simple convections (that have not been repeated) after a certain amount of time (3,5,10 years). These will probably be ignored in visa / residence permit affairs.

Comment: @Traveller the conviction may not result in an automatic finding that the person is a threat to public safety, even if it is a murder conviction.